# Hibernate: Multiple Parents to a child mapping

Tags: hibernate

I have these java classes:

```
Class Table1 
{  Integer id; 
   Set<Error> errors;
}
Class Table2
{  Integer id;  
   Set<Error> errors;
}
Class Table3
{ Integer id;   
  Set<Error> errors;
}

Class Error
{  
    Integer id;  
    Integer tableId;  // Pk of parent id  
    String tableName;  
    String errorMessage
}
```

How best to map them in Hibernate.

I tried this mapping:

```
<hibernate-mapping>
<class name="Table1" table="TABLE1" schema="xxx" catalog="XXXXX">
    <id name="id" type="integer">
        <column name="ID" />
        <generator class="native" />
    </id>
    <version column="MODIFIED_DATE" name="modifiedDate" 
                 type="timestamp"    unsaved-value="null"/>
    <set name="Errors" table="ERROR" fetch="join" 
            lazy="false" cascade="all-delete-orphan" where="TABLE_NAME='table1'">
        <key column ="TABLE_ID" not-null="true" />
        <one-to-many class="Error" />
    </set>

</class>
```

For the child:

```
<hibernate-mapping>
<class name="Error" table="ERROR" schema="XXX" catalog="xxxxx">
    <id name="id" type="integer">
        <column name="ID" />
        <generator class="native" />
    </id>
    <version column="MODIFIED_DATE" name="modifiedDate" type="timestamp" unsaved-value="null"/>
    <property name="tableId" type="integer" insert="false" update="false" >
        <column name="TABLE_ID" not-null="true" />
    </property>
    <property name="tableName" type="string">
        <column name="TABLE_NAME" not-null="true" length="20" />
    </property>
    <property name="errorMessage" type="string">
        <column name="ERROR_MESSAGE" length="100" />
    </property>
</class>
```

This works fine  if I have only table1, When I add the same mapping for table2, 
I get this error:

```
org.hibernate.MappingException: Repeated column in mapping for entity: Error column:
         TABLE_ID (should be mapped with insert="false" update="false")
```

Please help me with the correct mapping.

Thanks

Comment: can you show the mapping which gives you the error

Comment: I get this error when I have the mapping for table2 same as table1, just replacing table1 with table2. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

any mapping would be applicable here

```
Class Table1 implements HasErrors
{  Integer id; 
   Set<Error> errors;
}
Class Table2 implements HasErrors
{  Integer id;  
   Set<Error> errors;
}
Class Table3 implements HasErrors
{ Integer id;   
  Set<Error> errors;
}

Class Error
{  
    Integer id;  
    HasErrors parent;
    String errorMessage
}

    Integer tableId;  // Pk of parent id  
    String tableName;  

<class name="Error" table="ERROR" schema="XXX" catalog="xxxxx">
    ...
    <any name="parent" id-type="integer" meta-type="String">
      <meta-value value="Table1" class="Table1"/>
      <meta-value value="Table2" class="Table2"/>
      <column name="TABLE_NAME"/>
      <column name="TABLE_ID"/>
    </any>    
    <property name="errorMessage" type="string">
        <column name="ERROR_MESSAGE" length="100" />
    </property>
</class>

<class name="Table1" table="TABLE1" schema="xxx" catalog="XXXXX">
    ...
    <set name="errors" table="ERROR" lazy="false" cascade="all-delete-orphan" where="TABLE_NAME='table1'">
      <key column ="TABLE_ID" not-null="true" />
      <many-to-any id-type="integer" meta-type="String">
        <meta-value value="Table1" class="Table1"/>
        <meta-value value="Table2" class="Table2"/>
        <column name="TABLE_NAME" not-null="true"/>
        <column name="TABLE_ID" not-null="true"/>
      </many-to-any>
    </set>
</class>
```

Comment: Hi Firo, Thanks for your reply. I tried this mapping  but I got this error: org.hibernate.MappingException: could not interpret meta-value. Can you please elaborate or point to some documentation for its use? What methods does the interface have? I am trying to store errors from different tables(7) in a single error table with a discriminator "Table Name".  THANKS.

Comment: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/mapping.html#mapping-types-anymapping

Comment: Hi Firo, Thanks for that link. I couldn't get much help. I still couldn't figure out the error on the Child table mapping: rg.hibernate.MappingException: could not interpret meta-value. Can you please point me to right direction. THANKS.

Comment: a complete stacktrace would help. i thought there should be an inner exception